# $IMPORTSTATEMENT when create page in ionic2 CLI

Tags: angular, ionic2

Why $IMPORTSTATEMENT added in new created page 
When page is created from command line as 
**ionic g page [page_name]** 

In .ts file this code is added

[image]

Why this added in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try to update ionic, i update version 2 to 4.1.2 and it worked for me. Remember that you would have to migrate your app

`npm install -g ionic@4.1.2`